# Count duplicate data and store it to a variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I want to count the duplicated data in an array and store it to a variable. I managed to count it using `array_count_values()` but I dont know how to store it to a variabel. I tried to access the array from 'array_count_values()' but it give an error with `Undefined offset`

Here is my controller

```
 $query  = DB::table("detiltransaksiservice")->leftJoin('service', 'service.kodeService', 'detiltransaksiservice.kodeService')
    ->select('service.keterangan')->get();
    $count  = count($query);
    $kode   = [];
    $query = $query->toArray();
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
        $kode[$i] = $query[$i]->keterangan;
    }
    $test = array_count_values($kode);
    dd($test[0]);
```

And here is the `array_count_values()`

[image]

I want to store the biggest number from `array_count_values()`, in my case its 2 and Service Stang a different variable. Hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: Do yo plan extracting more data from the query results? Because if not you can do it directly on the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A probably better way is to create a query that gets this result for you, by using aggregate functions `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY` with `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`.

```
$result = DB::table("detiltransaksiservice")->leftJoin('service', 'service.kodeService', 'detiltransaksiservice.kodeService')
    ->select('service.keterangan', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total'))
    ->groupBy('service.keterangan')
    ->havingRaw("COUNT(*) > 1")
    ->get();
```

---

If you however want to do it in PHP, you can use `array_filter()`.

You can filter the result from `array_count_values()` by counts greater than one. Given that it could theoretically be more than one entry that has more than two occurrences, it would be best to keep it as an indexed array.

```php
$array = ['Service Mesin Ringan' => 1, 'Service Stang' => 2, 'Service Kabel' => 1];
$array = array_filter($array, function($v) { return $v > 1; });
var_dump($array);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["Service Stang"]=>
  int(2)
}
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/fKKco

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this:

```php
$query  = DB::table("detiltransaksiservice")
    ->leftJoin(
        'service',
        'service.kodeService',
        'detiltransaksiservice.kodeService'
    )
    ->select('service.keterangan')->get();

$test = $query->filter(
    function ($item) {
        return $item->keterangan === 'Service Stang';
    }
)->count();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use collection helper to achieve this\

```
$filtered = $query->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return $value > 1;
});
```

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-filter) is the official documentation of it.

> Note: Recommended to use before `$query = $query->toArray();` line.